# How do I slice an image of size "width × height" in n² pieces of size "width / n × height / n"?

Tags: graphics, programming, image-processing

Background: What I want is to make a jigsaw from an image. (A simple one where the pieces are polygons.) I have the following strategy in mind. Create a set of polygons and assign images (or just the original image) to them as a texture and set the texture coordinates. I know from the documentation (Lena example) how to use an image as a texture. Is chopping up the image in parts and assign these parts as textures a feasible strategy? If so, then I have the following question:

**Question: Given an image of size width × height, how do I slice it in n² pieces of size width / n × height / n ?**

Comment: Considering I often underestimate Mathematica you can imagine how content I am with the product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ImagePartition[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImagePartition.html) is the function you need:

```
With[{n = 4, img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}]}, 
  ImagePartition[img, Scaled[{1/n, 1/n}]]] // GraphicsGrid
```

[image: partitioned image]

See the docs for more details.

Comment: I prefer Lena ..

Comment: @bel: Well, I could've used Lena, but I'm told she was tired at the time...

Comment: Of course: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~chuck/lennapg/lenna.shtml

Comment: @bel: more precisely, I made use of her picture already as [an answer to another image-related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/92176)...